# Sin() Taylor sequence simplified - comments please

Tags: sequences-and-series

First of all, I will try to not be prolix, what is difficult for me, I apologize for that.

Searching simplified ways to write microcontrollers 8 bits assembly programs for log, sin and cos, guided me through Sin() Taylor sequence:

$$\ sin(rad) = rad - \frac{rad^3}{3!}+\frac{rad^5}{5!}-\frac{rad^7}{7!}+\frac{rad^9}{9!}...$$

Of course, dealing with this magnitude of numbers complicates assembly code using integers, made me search for some kind of relationship between each of the groups above, like for example, what is the value of  $$\ N1 = \frac{rad^3}{3!}/\frac{rad^5}{5!}$$ $$\ N2 = \frac{rad^5}{5!}/\frac{rad^7}{7!}$$ $$\ N3 = \frac{rad^7}{7!}/\frac{rad^9}{9!}$$ and so on.

I found that N2/N1 = 3.3333 and N3/N2 = 2.1 constants, no matter the value of **rad**.  It goes on, N3/N1 = 7, N4/N1 = 12, N5/N1 = 18.333 and so on.

Lets call those constants K, and I develop a formula to calculate them based on the group number "g".

$$\ Kg = \frac{(4g^2 + 10g + 6)}{6}$$

So we have constants K1, K2, K3 ... no matter **rad**.

Finding the constants allow a simple progressive division among the groups, instead of calculating individual groups based on exponents and factorials up to 9 or greater.  The progressive divisions use smaller numbers.

The values of N1, N2, N3, N4... can be calculated without using Taylor groups.  We just need to find out the N1, then apply the constants to find N2, N3, N4...

So, I found out that

$ N1 = \frac{6}{rad^2}$

and subsequently using the constants

$ N2 = N1 * 3.33333 $

$ N3 = N1 * 7 $

$ N4 = N1 * 12 $

$ N5 = N1 * 18.3333 $

```
Example, Sin(30) or Sin(0.523598776) in radians.
```

$ N1 = \frac{6}{rad^2} = \frac{6}{0.274155678} = 21.88537$

$N2 = N1 * 3.3333 = 72.9512 $

$N3 = N1 * 7 = 153.1975 $

$N4 = N1 * 12 = 262.6236 $

```
Now lets calculate the groups.
```

$ G1 = \frac{Rad}{N1} = \frac{0.5235}{21.88527} = 0.023924596 $

$ G2 = \frac{G1}{N2} = \frac{0.023923596}{72.9512} = 0.000327953 $

$ G3 = \frac{G2}{N3} = \frac{0.000327953}{153.19762} = 0.00000214072 $

$ G4 = \frac{G3}{N4} = \frac{0.00000214072}{262.6245} = 8.15126E-09 $

```
Then, finally:
```

$ Sin(30) = Rad - G1 + G2 - G3 + G4 = 0.5 $

For certain applications where high precision is not necessary, G4 and above becomes needed only for angles approaches PI/2, as Taylor's.

Using G1~G3, the errors vs Excel's sin() function are: Sin(30) E-09, Sin(89) E-04. Including G4, Sin(30) E-11, Sin(89) E-06, exactly as Taylor's.

To math prove my findings, I run an Excel table from 1 to 90 degrees plus few decimals as 30.01°, 30.1°.  The results match exactly Taylor sequence.

Scaling the numbers to integers, it becomes easy to process **sin(x)** with a 8 bit microcontroller as the AVRs, in assembler, for a speedy small code, without needing to calculate large exponents and factorials at all as Taylor requires, or using tables and interpolation.

I know, I write to much, but to calculate **sin(rad)** everything is presented on the last two blocks above, under "example". Only N1 requires the Rad value, the rest is based on constants.

As I couldn't find it anywhere at the Internet, I would appreciate your comments, good or bad.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Volder's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC)?

Comment: One way to greatly reduce the effects of round-off and truncation errors is to calculate a polynomial such as $r-r^3/3!+r^5/5!-r^7/7!+r^9/9!$ as $r(1-[s/2\cdot 3](1-[s/4\cdot 5](1-[s/6\cdot 7](1-[s/8\cdot 9]))))$ with $s=r^2$, when $r$ is "not big".